# How convert date properly in ReactJS frontend side

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, spring-boot

My API return some array of objects with LocalDate string and when I get it in my frontend side I want to convert it from state to JS Date object with timezone.

I tried to do it in componentDidMount() function after fetching API data but after setting state  react developer tool shows me that dateList state is udentified.

DateComponent

```
class DateComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dateList: [],
            id: this.props.id,

        }

    }

    componentDidMount() {
       DateService.retrieveProfile(this.state.id)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    dateList:this.convertDatesToTimezoneUTC(response.data.dateList)
                })
            })
    }

    convertDatesToTimezoneUTC(dateList) {
       dateList.map((value) => (
                value.date = new Date(value.date),
            )
        );
    }


    render() {
        let {dateList, id} = this.state;

          return (
            <div>
              <Formik
               enableReinitialize
               initialValues={{dateList}}>
                <FieldArray name="dateList"
                     render={() => (
                        <div>
                             {dateList.map((value, index) => (
                              <div className={"m-3 form-row"} id={value.id} key={index}>
                               <Field className="form-control col-md-2 mr-2" type="text"
                                                           name={`dateList[${index}].date`} readOnly/>

                    </Formik>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DateComponent;
```

Model

```
dateList[{
id:"some id"
date:"2019-08-16"
}]
```

Without convert convertDatesToTimezoneUTC() function everything is alright and return data properly. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forgot to `return` from the `convertDatesToTimezoneUTC()`:

```
convertDatesToTimezoneUTC(dateList) {
  return dateList.map((value) => (
    value.date = new Date(value.date),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Exactly ! Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` your newly computed `array` from `convertDatesToTimezoneUTC` function, also you need to only change the `date` and keep rest of the object properties as it is,

```
convertDatesToTimezoneUTC = (dateList) => {
   return dateList.map((value) => ({
            ...value,
            date : new Date(value.date),
          })
        )
}
```

Comment: Thats even better option for me , I'm gonna use that.  Thanks !

Comment: You should use this only, it will also keep your `id` from dateList which you are using to display.